# Error on creating custom log4j Appender

Tags: java, jpa, log4j, cdi

I'm trying to create a custom Appender that will persist logs to the database using JPA.

The thing is that I'm using `PersistenceContext` attribute like this

```
package com.foobar.logging;

import com.foobar.model.SysLog;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.MDC;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class LogManager extends AppenderSkeleton {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent le) {
        SysLog log = new SysLog();
        log.setDescripcion(le.getMessage().toString());
        if (MDC.get("IdUsuario") != null) {
            log.setIdUsuario(MDC.get("IdUsuario").toString());
        }
        log.setSysAccionLog(null);

        this.em.persist(log);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now when I'm deploying the WAR to JBoss AS 7.1, it fails, and I get the error:

`java.lang.VerifyError: class com.foobar.logging.LogManager$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$ overrides final method getName.()Ljava/lang/String;`

How can I use CDI to inject my EntityManager inside an AppenderSkeleton?  Has anyone accomplished JPA persistance in an AppenderSkeleton using CDI?

I also tried not using CDI, but since every other object in my app uses it (JAX-RS classes), it collapses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EJBs are proxies.  `AppenderSkeleton` has a `getName` method that is final.  I think for your use case, you need to implement `Appender` directly.  This will avoid the bean method `getName`

However, I have to question the idea of trying to make an appendar an EJB.  How are you instantiating it?